# Store sequence of images in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I tried to store images using CoreData. It is fine and I can store a single image. However how can I turn it to multiple images?

[image]

Currently, I have set the image field to Binary Data.

I save the image into the object by:

```
let imageData = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "Dummy1").jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
item.image = imageData
try? self.viewContext.save()
```

How can I turn it into an array of imageData that can store in CoreData?

I tried to do this but it fails:

```
let imageData1 = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "Dummy1").jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
let imageData2 = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "Dummy2").jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
item.image = [imageData1, imageData2]
try ? self.viewContext.save()
```

The compiler said that the attribute 'image' is Data? but not [Data]? type.

I have also tried to use the Type Transformable:

[image]

However, there is warning:
warning: Misconfigured Property: Items.imageArray is using a nil or insecure value transformer. Please switch to NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName or a custom NSValueTransformer subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer

Any idea on the warning and how to resolve it?

On using the Transformable type, actually I can achieve this:

```
let imageData1 = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "Dummy1").jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
let imageData2 = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "Dummy2").jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
item.image = imageData1
item.imageArray = [imageData1!, imageData2!]
```

However, a few issues here:

- It force to add ! to imageData, which indeed, should be optional in my case, I have no way to use ?? properly to give it a dummy imageData if that is found to be nil.

The same problem appear when I tried to display the array:

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: (self.item.imageArray![0]))!)
            .frame(width:300, height:300)
```

You can see that I have added ! to both imageArray! which can be nil and also the UIImage!

I would like to, instead provide default values for both cases, but I failed to use ?? to provide default value. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to jam a square peg in a round hole. You can't assign an array of data into a data property or a transformable property because an array of data is neither data nor a transformable.

What you can do is to make your property a one-to-many relationship with another entity, let's call it `ImageContainer`, this other entity would have an `imageData` property. Now you could add as many images (within an image container) to your object.

Another alternative is to use a transformable value, which as I understand uses `NSSecureCoding` to transform your values into something CoreData can understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should not save images directly in database, you will hit big performance issues.

Instead save the image name in the database and save the actual image with [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) in the storage.

Then you can load the image/s from the file manager.